# Passing user data with glade/gtkbuilder

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am a newbie of glade/pygtk.

I am doing with some radio menu items. 
I created a signal handler on the signals tab,

handler: on_group_menu_change
user data:  7

what I expected is pass the int(or str) value **7** as user param to the handler. However, at startup, I found such warning:

> Could not lookup object 0 on signal
>   group_changed of object radiomenuitem1

I know gtkBuilder treat **7** as an object reference.

So how can I just pass an int/str to the handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is still on the Glade/GtkBuilder todo-list: http://live.gnome.org/Glade/Roadmap/RealUsableSignals

Currently you can only pass references to objects that you define in your xml.

Edit: Since gtk+3, the devs have broken more than just the API... The archived link above is:
https://web.archive.org/web/20100510072526/http://live.gnome.org/Glade/Roadmap/RealUsableSignals

Comment: Here, "references" means the name of an object. I just figured that out after source-diving into GTK+. GtkBuilder looks for the "user data" (rendered as 'object="foo"' in XML) in the same hash table as the one it uses to find objects in gtk_builder_get_object().